# Httpwebrequest System.UriFormatException: 'Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.' error

Tags: .net, vb.net

i have sample code which use httpwebrequest but one of line Httpwebrequest have

return  System.UriFormatException: 'Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.' error.

i don't understand why error return .

anyone would give me tip much appreciate!

```
Dim postData As String = ""
Dim logincookie
Dim tempcookies As New CookieContainer
Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)
Dim postreq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create("https://blog.naver.com/bikeshin?Redirect=Log&logNo=221466829247"), HttpWebRequest)
postreq.Method = "GET"
postreq.KeepAlive = True
postreq.CookieContainer = tempcookies
postreq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/4.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729"
postreq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
postreq.Referer = "https://search.naver.com/search.naver?where=post&sm=tab_jum&query=%EC%98%81%ED%99%94"
Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse
postresponse = DirectCast(postreq.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)
tempcookies.Add(postresponse.Cookies)
logincookie = tempcookies
Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())
Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd
WebBrowser1.DocumentText = thepage

Dim urladdress As String = "https//blog.naver.com/PostView.nhn?blogId=bikeshin&logNo=221466829247&from=search&redirect=Log&widgetTypeCall=true&topReferer=https://search.naver.com/search.naver?where=post&sm=tab_jum&query=%EC%98%81%ED%99%94&directAccess=false"
postreq = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(urladdress), HttpWebRequest)   ' <== in here have return error
postreq.Method = "GET"
postreq.KeepAlive = True
postreq.CookieContainer = tempcookies
postreq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/4.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729"
postreq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
postreq.Referer = "https://search.naver.com/search.naver?where=post&sm=tab_jum&query=%EC%98%81%ED%99%94"

postresponse = DirectCast(postreq.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)
tempcookies.Add(postresponse.Cookies)
logincookie = tempcookies
'Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())
thepage = postreqreader.ReadToEnd
```

Comment: `Dim urladdress As String = "https//blog…` missing colon. Use `https://blog…`.

Comment: Please **delete** this question. It's off-topic here because … _This question was **caused by** a problem that can no longer be reproduced or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._